# Need Fastest Search Method in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Consider a scenario, I have 2 columns (Column "A" & Column "B").

Column A has around 130000 rows/Strings
Column B has around 10000 rows/Strings

I would like to search each string of Column "B" from Column "A".

As you can see the volume of data is very high. I have already tried with Range.Find() method. But it's taking lot of time to complete. I am searching for a method/way that will give me result in very less turnaround time.

* Some more Clarification on my requirement ***

(1) Column A & B contains string values, NOT NUMBERS. And the string can be very large

(2) For each cell in column "B", There can be many occurrence in column "A"

(3) I would like to fetch all the occurrence of column "B"  in column "A" with Row Number

(4) For a string present in column "B". It can be found as a Substring of any cell in column "A"

---

Download file link - wikisend.com/download/431054/StackOverFlow_Sample.xlsx ***

Any Suggestions ?

Feel free incase you need any extra details to solve above problem !

Comment: It depends on what your sorting criteria is really... maybe you could post some more info and/or code.

Comment: well, how about [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567060/excel-vba-fast-compare-method-of-2-columns/19570501#19570501)?

Comment: @mehow I tried your code, It has been running for more than 20 seconds, I had to end task it. Maybe I was doing something wrong. Would you like to try your code for the data I potrayed?

Comment: Comparison of different methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285   Didn't include the collection method posted by @SiddharthRout though, so that's a good addition....

Comment: What are the average lengths of the strings in columns A and B? I don't have access to your spreadsheet at work and I'm testing some solutions.

Comment: The average length of Column A string is around "100"  & For columns B it's around "20".

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

This took `3` seconds for `130000 rows in Col A` and `10000 rows in Col B`. The output is generated in `Col C`.

**NOTE**: I have taken the `worst` case scenario where all `10000` values in Col B are present in Col A

This is how my data looks.

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Now

    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws
        .Range("C1:C10000").Value = "No"

        For i = 1 To 130000
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To 10000
            col.Add .Range("B" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("B" & i).Value)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then .Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes"
            Err.Clear
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

And this was the result

[image]

Comment: @SamWard: Yes, `Countif/Vlookup/Find` creates havoc on such humongous range so I moved on to collections for this. And not to mention, 3 Second on a worst case scenario ;)

Comment: +1 quite well designed code and good approach. Unnecessary casting  though `.Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)` as `.Range("A" & i)` default property is value. worth noticing that [`.Value2` is faster than `.Value`](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/). Try without explicit casting and add Option CompareText on the top instead :) see if you can gain an extra second hehe

Comment: @mehow: Yup. But I fully qualify my code even though it is a default property. Old habits die hard ;) Agree on the value2.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks for the quick & interesting solution. But I won't be having numbers in column "A" or "B". they can have large strings. for each value of column "B" there can be many matches in column "A" and I would like to fetch all the matches of column "B" in column "A". I have updated my question. Pls have a look for more details. Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yes, I have tested it. It's not working :( Could you please go through my question again. I have added more details in it.

Comment: @SolutionSeeker: Yes, with the new info that you added, the above code would not suffice. Care to upload a sample file so that I can test the new code before I post it? If yes, then you can upload it in any free file sharing site like www.wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I have uploaded my file to below link. I would like to search all the occurrence of each cell present in column "B" of sheet(tab2) from column "A" of sheet(tab1). Thanks ***http://wikisend.com/download/431054/StackOverFlow_Sample.xlsx***

Comment: @SolutionSeeker: I am still trying to find a better way to achieve what you want. The data you have is so large and the operation that we are trying is complex. I have already tried 2-3 methods and all of them are taking more than 10 mins to run. I am still trying. Let me see if I come up with a faster solution.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks a lot for helping me out. By the way I am ok if the whole macro completes execution in 20-25 mins. Pls do let me know what are the methods that you tried. Even I can try them out from my end with some R&D. Thanks again :)

Comment: @SolutionSeeker: Quick question. I noticed something weird. There are 70615 duplicates in Col A and 551 duplicates in Col B. So actually you have 61954 rows in Col A and 9440 rows in Col B. Were you aware of that?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yes, I knew that. I want to proceed with these data only. There were many columns in my spreadsheet. But I gave you only 1 column that I want to search for. Others I have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW**
Column A 130000 100-character strings, Column B 10000 30-character strings, 27 minutes.

Column C is populated with row locations of occurrences of Column B string.
Column D is populated with number of occurrences of Column B string.

```
Public Sub searchcells()
    Dim arrA(1 To 130000) As String, arrB(1 To 10000) As String, t As Date, nLen As Integer
    t = Now
    Me.Range("c:d") = ""

    For i = 1 To 130000
        arrA(i) = Me.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 10000
        arrB(i) = Me.Cells(i, 2)
    Next

    For i = 1 To 130000
        nLen = Len(arrA(i))
        For j = 1 To 10000
            If InStrRev(arrA(i), arrB(j), nLen - Len(arrB(j)) + 1) > 0 Then Me.Cells(j, 4) = Me.Cells(j, 4) + 1: Me.Cells(j, 3) = Me.Cells(j, 3) & i & "; "
        Next
        Me.Cells(1, 5) = i
    Next

    Debug.Print CDbl(Now - t) * 24 * 3600 & " seconds"
End Sub
```

The cells can be populated easily with the following, changing i and j limits for the desired number of strings and string lengths in each section.

```
Public Sub fillcells()
    Dim temp As String
    Randomize

    For i = 1 To 13000
        temp = ""
        For j = 1 To 100
            temp = temp & Chr(70 + Int(10 * Rnd()))
        Next
        Me.Cells(i, 1) = temp
    Next
    For i = 1 To 10000
        temp = ""
        For j = 1 To 30
            temp = temp & Chr(70 + Int(10 * Rnd()))
        Next
        Me.Cells(i, 2) = temp
    Next
End Sub
```

I am unable to download your spreadsheet at work, so disregard this if it missed the mark.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually each string is very large in length. Length is around 100 characters per string. try to download my spreadsheet from below link. *****wikisend.com/download/431054/StackOverFlow_Sample.xlsx****

Comment: Are the Column B strings also ~100 characters? I'm at work and cannot download from wikisend :(

Comment: All the cells of Column "A" string length = 100 & all the cells of Column "B" length is around 30

Comment: Haha, WAY slower! ~27 hours.

Comment: Ok, got it down to 27 minutes by not checking past the length of the Column B string.