# Excel VBA - Compare List in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have 2 Lists which need to be compared, this always takes a few hours, so maybe this process can be optimized.

**List1** only Contains usernames:

```
michael1
michael2
bernd1
david1
julia2
...
```

**List2** contains Usernames, First Names and Last Names:

```
julian1         Julian         Müller
michael1        Michael        Rink
bernd1          Bernd          Miller
david1          David          Nelz
.....
```

So now I'd like to sort them like this:

```
Column A: Values from First List
Column B: EMPTY
Column C: Usernames from List2
Column D: First Names from List2
Column E: Last Names from List2
```

All Usernames from `List1` which are not on `List2` or vice-versa should be listed either in Columns G, H, I or in a separate Excel file.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using a VBA Code to search each Username, but it crashed due to so much data. This is for my Work, we dont have "Super-Computers".

Comment: Can you post the VBA Code that you used and the error message you recieved, maybe we can help you optimise it.

Comment: sorry - I Cant give you the exact code, because it crashed :/ it wasnt a long code, but here is a small part i still remember: Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Username).Row

Comment: How many rows of data approximately in List 1 and List 2?

Comment: You can do this with the `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: Please take a look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840955/need-fastest-search-method-in-excel-vba

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MATCH and VLOOKUP are the excel functions you will need to solve this in excel sheet without using VBA.

In a column next to list 1 you can use MATCH in each cell to indicate in a cell whether the username in list 2 is in list 1.  (eg =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(I3,$F$3:$F$6,0)),FALSE,TRUE)     where $F$3:$F$6 is the range of list 1 and I3 is an list 2 cell).

Similarly in list 2 you can add columns  that use VLOOKUP in each cell to lookup the username from list 1 in list 2 but get a value from another cell in list 2.  (See help for details of how to use this)

So this give you the info you need, you just need to merge it together.

You simply need to add the List 1 usernames that are indicated as not being in list 2 to the end of list 1.

It might be that you can easily do this manually.  For instance by using autofilters to show only missing one then copy and paste these.

I know this is not a complete answer, but you info is brief.

Let me now if this helps and how you get on.

Harvey