# Is there any fast way to copy Duplicate rows(next to each other) from a Sheet to another by analyzing multiple columns in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I want to copy duplicate rows from a sheet to another by analyzing multiple columns in excel, I can do it by applying Nested For loops to compare multiple columns but number of rows in my sheet is around 6000. So if I apply nested For loop to compare rows by analyzing 2 columns it requires around 17991001 iterations, which slows down my System. Is there any fast way to do that???

my Function is

```
Sub findDuplicates(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, name As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByVal Sheet2 As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numRow As Integer
    'Dim matchFound As Long
    'Dim myRange1 As Range
    'Dim myRange2 As Range



    numRow = sheet.Range("J2", sheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    With Sheet2
        Range(Cells(row, "A"), Cells(row, "N")).MergeCells = True
        With Cells(row, "A")
            .Font.name = "Bell MT"
            .Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
            .Font.Size = 20
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 99, 71)
            .Value = "Multiple Forms Found in " & name & " for single household"
        End With
        row = row + 1
    End With
        For i = 1 To numRow + 1
            'matchFound
            'If i <> matchFound Then
            sheet.Rows(i).Copy Sheet2.Rows(row)
            row = row + 1
            'sheet.Rows(matchFound).Copy Sheet2.Rows(row)
            'row = row + 1
           'End If

        Next i
End Sub
```

Note - I added some comments to make you understand what I want to do.

The Summery of my function is to take two sheets and check the J and K columns of sheet 1, If two rows found same J and K column's value then both rows are copied to sheet2 (next to each other)

Comment: When you are inside `With Sheet2 ... end with` `Range` becomes `.Range` (same for cells) to pass along the parent worksheet. I'm also unclear on what `row = row + 1` accomplishes since row is never assigned a value to begin with.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you say two rows are duplicates when a number of specific cells are the same. In this case I would generate a key from the values of the given cells, collect them to an array, apply some sorting algorithm (for 6000 rows a bubblesort will do), so you'll need to compare adjacent values only.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it clearer. I can't undestand the merging, row variable, and which columns you want to compare.

Comment: create keys through concatenation of fields, use countif to count, filter and sort descending?

Comment: @Jeeped i added row variable as a parameter and using it as a reference, Its just used to track the row number where the new data is to be add. Whenever i added a new row to a sheet i just incremented a row number by 1

Comment: @AcsErno By sorting 6000 rows with bubble sort It will take some higher time, because time complexity of bubble sort is n^2 i.e. n*n. It means for 6000 rows i have to iterate swapping of data to 6000*6000 times, It is much higher

Comment: @CMArg The Summery of my function is to take two sheets and check the J and K columns of sheet 1, If two rows found same J and K column's value then both rows are copied to sheet2 (next to each other)

Comment: @QHarr Is there any way to bypass the last phase i.e. Sorting
I have the technique in my mind But I don,t know how to code it
Can you please help me

I just want to use single match formula for two columns
I want to match row found is same row then continue to next 
If its not the same row then copy the row found and the iterated row

Comment: VBA is much faster when you work within it and avoid frequent access to Excel. So give a try sorting in memory. You shouldn't expect sorting time to exceed 0.1 sec for 6000 strings. 
I suggested bubblesort because it is easy to implement (<10 lines) but it is your choice to select the most appropriate sorting method. Btw the number of loops is n*(n+1)/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, This Works for me

```
Sub findDuplicates(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, name As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByVal Sheet2 As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim numRow As Integer
    Dim count As Integer 
    Dim myRange1 As Range
    Dim myRange2 As Range
    Dim myRange3 As Range

    Set myRange1 = sheet.Range("J2", sheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Rows
    Set myRange2 = sheet.Range("K2", sheet.Range("K2").End(xlDown)).Rows
    numRow = sheet.Range("J2", sheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

    With Sheet2
        Range(Cells(row, "A"), Cells(row, "N")).MergeCells = True
        With Cells(row, "A")
            .Font.name = "Bell MT"
            .Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
            .Font.Size = 20
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 99, 71)
            .Value = "Multiple Forms Found in " & name & " for single household"
        End With
        sheet.Rows(1).Copy .Rows(row + 1)
        .Rows(row + 1).WrapText = False
        row = row + 2
    End With
    j = row
    For i = 1 To numRow + 1
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(myRange1, sheet.Cells(i, "J"), myRange2, sheet.Cells(i, "K"))
        If count > 1 Then
            sheet.Rows(i).Copy Sheet2.Rows(row)
            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Set myRange3 = Sheet2.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(row - 1, 192))
    With Sheet2.Sort
       .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J1"), Order:=xlAscending
       .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K1"), Order:=xlAscending
       .SetRange myRange3
       .Header = xlNo
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .Apply
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. Title is overwriting data (in Sheet1), and duplicate data is not next to each other...

Comment: @CMArg After Adding the title I added +2 to row so it will not overwrite
and for putting duplicate data next to each other I sorted it with same column on which I applied criteria to check the duplicacy. i.e. column J and K.

And its working Perfectly Working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Modified from Siddharth Rout's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841676/1726522).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lLastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).row

    DestSheetLastRow = 1
    With SourceSheet
        For i = 1 To lLastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add i, CStr(.Range("J" & i).Value) 'Add elements to collection
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'If element already present
                TheVal = CStr(SourceSheet.Range("J" & i).Value) 'Get the duplicate value
                TheIndex = col(TheVal) 'Get the original position of duplicate value in the collection (i.e., the row)
                If (.Cells(i, 11).Value = .Cells(TheIndex, 11).Value) Then 'Check the other column (K). If same value...
                    SourceSheet.Range(Cells(TheIndex, 1), Cells(TheIndex, 20)).Copy DestSheet.Cells(DestSheetLastRow, 1) 'Set your range according to your needs. 20 columns in this example
                    SourceSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Copy DestSheet.Cells(DestSheetLastRow, 21)
                    DestSheetLastRow = DestSheetLastRow + 1
                    Err.Clear
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```