# Speed up the deletion of duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I coded a VBA script in Excel which adds new data into a Datasheet with previous information. Before doing that, the new data is copied into a provisional Datasheet. To prevent duplicates, I create an additional column and do a VLOOKUP of IDs. If the ID from the new imported data is already in the Datasheet with the old data, this row is marked as duplicated and will be deleted. The "non-duplicated rows" are then copied into the final Datasheet, where all the data is stored.

Right now I use a column reference (A:A) in the VLOOKUP and I don´t know if maybe this is the reason why the VBA script needs every day more resources and time to run. When I coded for the first time, I did the test with no more than 4,000 rows in the original Datasheet and 4,000 rows in the imported data. The macro was done after 90 seconds. Right now, it needs more than 5 minutes and the Datasheet with data is just 40,000 rows large, while the new data is always around 4,000 rows.

Should I dynamically reference the range in the VLOOKUP instead of using A:A or it doesn't matter in terms of speed?

Comment: Show your code. If you are using VLOOKUP function on a Worksheet, that would be very slow. YOu can do all this sort of operation within VBA without manipulating the worksheet. I might use a different function than VLOOKUP, though.  There are probably other ways to optimize, but we kinda need to see what you've done, first.

Comment: Dynamically referencing the range won't hurt, but using arrays for such large numbers of records would be my suggestion. Think about it this way, for each of the 4000 entries you have it is looking through 40,000 other entries to find a match. Are the ids numberical? Are they names? What does the data look like? There may be a much more efficient way of looking for duplicates. I would probably suggest you copy all the data and use the excel "Remove Duplicates" funciton under the "Data" ribbon, I just ran it against a dummy data set of 100,000 entries and it took 3 or 4 seconds.

Comment: If you have unique ID's then a `Scripting.Dictionary` lookup will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: See my answer here for performance comparison and approaches you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285

Comment: I drastically reduced run time by deleting the VLOOKUP procedure and doing just a Remove Duplicate as  @pegicity said (.Range("A2", "AR" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes) Thx

Comment: @pegicity add your solution as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: Agree with @TimWilliams. I'm so used to dictionaries for removing duplicates and storing key-value pairs that I'm *almost* dependent on it. The speed is just impossible to beat, though it takes some getting used to the set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, there certainly is a way to accomplish this task using VBA, but sometimes the simpliest solution is best.  I would reccomend added all 40K records each time and using the "Remove Duplicates" function under the "Data" ribbon using the column that holds your unique value.

Comment: and if you still want to use a macro this line will do it (Excel 2007 and over): .Range("Firstcolumnx", "Endcolumny").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes