# Is there a better alternative than a loop to reduce processing time?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am cycling through `values` on a pending data list and then updating a master list if any of those values are new.  The pending list will normally have 100-200 `rows` of data and each `row` will have about 10 `variables` that it will need to make sure are updated on the master list.  The Master list is about 10,000 `rows`.

I have written code that will `loop` through `each row` of the pending list, assign `values` to `variables` and then perform a `find` on the master list looking for a matching record and then update it accordingly.  My code works fine and does exactly what I want but the processing time is about 4 minutes and that's 3 minutes and 50 seconds longer than the people that use it are willing to allow without complaining.

Is there alternative coding that I could use to help decrease processing time?

The code I have is very long and so I am not going to paste it all here but instead paste snip-its of it so you can have an idea of what I am currently doing:

```
Application.Screenupdating = False
Applicaiton.Enableevents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PendingBRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PendingLog").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
MasterBRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterLog").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

For D = 2 To PendingBRow
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PendingLog").Range("A" & D)
PendingRecordNumber = .Value
PendingIR = .offset(0, 5).Value
PendingVal = .offset(0, 6).Value
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterLog").Range("B2:B" & MasterBRow)
Set c = .Find(PendingRecordNumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
DaysSinceLastWorkedStatic = c.offset(0, 22).Value


MasterIRValue = c.offset(0, 16).Value
            If PendingIR <> 0 Then
            If PendingIR <> MasterIRValue Then
            c.offset(0, 16).Value = PendingIR
            DaysSinceLastWorkedStatic = 0
            c.offset(0, 22).Value = DateVal
            End If
            End If

            c.offset(0, 24).Value = POorLA
            c.offset(0, 25).Value = FinalizedFlag
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress ' in rare cases a record number could be duplicated on the master list.  


end if
end with

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PendingLog").Range("A" & D).offset(0, 15).Value = DaysSinceLastWorkedStatic
Next D
```

One alternative I had considered was to filter the master list by the record number and update the visible row only and then unfilter for each record number on the pending list. I have not yet tested this method.

Could this method be better than what I have?

Comment: That's a long time to process that amount of data. You could try a test where you short-circuit the Find by using a fixed "update" row, and see what effect that has on your run time.  If it gets faster then try replacing the Find with (eg) a scripting dictionary-based "map" of Id vs row number.  And I would update that Find to use lookAt:=xlWhole otherwise if someone has previously used xlPart you may sometimes end up updating the wrong row.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285

Comment: Yeah, the find command is likely part of it.  One thing you might want to try is place some tracker varaibles checking the time here and there, and at the end display them.  Find which bits are running slow.\

Comment: @ Tim Williams Thanks Tim for your always prompt response.  Also, thank you for xlWhole advice.  I definitely will incorporate that.  As far as the find, I don't believe that it's what's holding up my code.  I think it more related to the c.offset(0, 22).Value = DateVal type code.  When I step through code it always seems to lag when it updates the values on the masterlog.  What do you think?  Also, do you have any thoughts on my alternative solution?

Comment: Try commenting out different parts of the code and see how the run time changes (maybe with just 50 records so it doesn't take all day)

Comment: @Timwilliams So I can confirm that the Find process, itself, is not the problem.  I commented out the code where it updated the values on the master log and it reran the code.  Total process time was about 6 seconds.  The problem is updating the values on the Master Log when a variable is different.  So c.offset(x,y).value = z  is the problem.  Is there a better way to update the master log? How about saving all values to an array and then apply the changes all at once to the master log?

Answer (score 3):

So I dont know if this will be an answer but I think this might at least give you a look at another type of find/update code.

This is used to update the times people are scheduled to work

In this example I have a Row A with Names B with Times.  I paste the updated Name and Time in rows H and I.  Some times its all 98 some times it just 5 and this program looks at the list finds the name and takes the time from I and writes it over its corresponding time in B.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Holiday()

Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim SrcRng      As Range
Dim schRng      As Range
Dim c           As Range
Dim search      As Range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
Set SrcRng = ws.Range("H2:H98")
Set schRng = ws.Range("A2:A98")


For Each c In SrcRng
    Set search = schRng.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(, 1).Copy search.Offset(, 1)

    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code example.  I am trying to incorporate it but I keep receiving a Run-Time Error 9, Subscript out of range.  Any recommendations?

Comment: I just tested this again and didnt get any issues try
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")

instead of the ws = thisworkbook.sheets(3)

Comment: I ended up having to put 'Find(What:= variable'. I am not sure why it required me to add the 'What:=' as opposed to just entering the search variable. I have another routine that does it that way with no issue.  Regardless, The find, itself, is not the problem.  The problem is the copying of data from one sheet to the other.  I am going to see about adding additional checks that could eliminate the need for the code to run at all.  I hope that help some.  I am also considering storing all the changes to an array and then update the other sheet 1 time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting would love to see what your solution is I do a lot of updating of random information and the find solution gets the job done but I am still not sold to if its the best solution.