# VBA macro in Excel fails on Dell computers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have started experiencing unpredictable results from a macro I've been using for years without any problems.

The code is below:

```
Sub FindMatchingData()

Dim MySearchRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim findC As Variant

Set MyRange = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Select the range of cells containing the data you are looking for:", Type:=8)

Set MySearchRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Select the range you wish to investigate:", Type:=8)

Response = InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the comment you wish to appear to indicate the data was found:")

MyOutputColumn = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Enter the alphabetical column letter(s) to specify the column you want the message to appear in.")

Set Sht = MyRange.Parent

  For Each c In MyRange
    If Not c Is Nothing Then

Set findC = MySearchRange.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not findC Is Nothing Then
           Sht.Range(MyOutputColumn & c.Row).Cells.Value = Response
        End If
    End If
  Next
Excel.Application.SendKeys Keys:="^{HOME}", Wait:=True
DoEvents
MsgBox "Investigation completed."

End Sub
```

In summary, this macro provides an easy way for users to find matching data between two ranges, either within the same worksheet or across worksheets within the same workbook.

The expected behaviour is as follows:

1. it prompts the user to:

   - select the range containing the data they're looking for
   - select the range to be searched to see if the data also exists there
   - enter a comment that is used to indicate any matching data
   - enter the column you want the comment populated into if a match was found
2. Excel then proceeds to run the comparison between the selected ranges and starts populating the selected column wherever matches are found.
3. When complete it presents the user with an *Investigation completed* message.

For example, if the user selects range A2:A40000 in Sheet 1 as containing the data to look for, and then selects range C2:C2000 in Sheet 2 as the range to search, and then enters the word "Yes" as the comment followed by selecting D as the column, the expected result when complete is that the user will see that cells in Column D in Sheet 1 will contain the word "Yes" if the data was found.

The reason I am experiencing unexpected results during the past few weeks is that sometimes the macro runs fine and other times it gets stuck in an endless loop and doesn't complete (it doesn't produce an error, it's just still processing).

However, I have just conducted a test of the same macro on the same spreadsheet with the following results:

- on a 6yr old HP EliteBook 8470p laptop (8GB RAM, 512GB HDD, Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Excel 2010) the macro successfully completes in 17m 06s
- on a 2mth old Dell Latitude 5480 laptop (16GB RAM, SSD, Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Excel 2010) the macro is still processing at 6h 24m
- on a 2yr old iMac desktop (running Windows 10 with Excel 365 on a Parallels virtual machine) the macro successfully completes in 2m 21s
- on a 8yr old HP Compaq dc7900 desktop (8GB RAM, HDD, Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Excel 2010) the macro successfully completes in 24m 34s
- on a 1wk old Dell 7050 desktop (16GB RAM, SSD, Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Excel 2010) the macro is still processing at 1h 49m

So, in summary:

- the macro has worked perfectly for over 5 years
- testing the macro with exactly the same Excel spreadsheet on five different computers results in two of them essentially failing to complete
- the only thing the two that fail have in common is that they're both newer Dell machines
- one of the tests that succeeded was actually run in a virtual environment on a Mac

**Question:** Is there anything in the code that could explain why the macro fails to complete in the two Dell computers?

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong to me, but as a first step in debugging, you may consider adding some MsgBox (or Debug.Print) statements and/or breakpoints throughout the procedure. This would help you identify where the failure occurs. Obviously, you know it's working as far as the InputBoxes are concerned, so I would begin with some print/breakpoints within your loop. Make sure it's executing at all. Possible culprit might be the `SendKeys` with the wait parameter...

Comment: Excel doesn't run differently on Dell (or any other brand of computers) running the same versions of Excel and Windows. You either have a bug in your code that is only triggering under certain circumstances, or a mismatch in Excel versions that change the behavior of the code. My bet would be on the first, as Excel doesn't break backward compatibility in existing code very often (and when it does it's typically documented). Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger on the problem machines?

Comment: `If Not c Is Nothing Then` should be `If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then` or similar.  c will never be Nothing in this case.  Also maybe try being more explicit in your Find() by providing the `LookAt` argument (otherwise you get the last-used value for that, which may differ from run to run)

Comment: If you're looking for exact matches then Match() will be much faster than Find().   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285

Comment: @DavidZemens Excellent suggestion, I'll start doing that now to see if I can narrow down the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite Exactly, it should be the same across the same versions of Excel. And, thinking about it now, it's not that it always fails on the Dell machines (I use the macro on lots of different spreadsheets), it's just that whenever it has failed it's always been on the Dells and not the others. In any case, I'm starting to do some debugging now to see if I can narrow down a problem in the code.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams I'll have a play and see what happens.

Comment: You're writing to the workbook - if `Application.EnableEvents` is `True`, `Application.Calculation` is `xlCalculationAutomatic`, and `Application.ScreenUpdating` is `True`, then... Excel is basically choking under an ever-growing pile of things to do, and can't keep up. Try turning app events off, setting calculation to manual, and if all goes well, disabling screen repaints... as for that `SendKeys` and `DoEvents`.. I think you mean to just do `Sht.Range("A1").Select`.

Comment: Watch for undeclared variables (is `Option Explicit` missing at the top of the module?), and consider what happens if the user cancels an `Application.InputBox` that prompts for a `Range` object, too: the function returns a `Variant/Boolean` then, and `Set MySearchRange` blows up with a *type mismatch* error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Been doing a fair bit of testing and none of my changes resolved the issue (although I didn't get a chance to properly implement using `Match()` instead of `Find()`. But today I decided to disable events, automatic calculations and screen updating and the macro now works perfectly on the Dell computers.

Comment: I'll never know why the previous version works fine on the other machines (even tested it yesterday on the current macOS version of Excel and it works fine, so not working in Windows on a Dell machine is bizarre), but your input was invaluable and got this sorted for me. So, if you wanted to add that as an answer I'd be more than happy to except it! :) And, thanks again! :)

Comment: @TimWilliams This (using `Match()` instead of `Find()`) looks promising for future reference and I'm still playing with this. In the meantime I've got around my problem by disabling events, automatic calculations and screen updating. However, I've upvoted your answer in that other post and will continue to experiment with ti.