# VBA Function: Faster Way to Index Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which I use to do a two-column lookup and return a third value. I however need to call this function frequently within a macro to return the corresponding value and it dramatically increases execution time. Is there a faster way to lookup values?

```
Function FindValue(rng1 As Variant, rng2 As Variant) As Variant
Dim varVal1 As Variant
Dim varVal2 As Variant
Dim rngTargetA As Range
Dim rngTargetB As Range
Dim lngRowCounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

varVal1 = rng1
varVal2 = rng2

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("TargetSheet")
lngRowCounter = 2
Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Do While Not IsEmpty(rngTargetA.Value)
    If rngTargetA.Value = varVal1 And rngTargetB.Value = varVal2 Then
        FindValue = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter).Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngRowCounter = lngRowCounter + 1
    Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
    Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Loop

' if we don't find anything, return an empty string '
FindValue = "Nothing"


End Function
```

Sample data i'm working with:

| DATE | CURRENCY | DAY TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | TWD | New Years Day |
| 1/1/2022 | USD | New Years Day |
| 1/1/2022 | VND | New Years Day |
| 1/1/2022 | ZAR | New Years Day |
| 1/2/2022 | ARS | Weekend |
| 1/2/2022 | AUD | Weekend |
| 1/2/2022 | BRL | Weekend |
| 1/2/2022 | CAD | Weekend |
| 1/2/2022 | CHF | Berchtoldstag |

My attempt with results for a table with 10'000 rows:
Is there a faster way yet?

```
Weekend
This code ran successfully in 9.99999977648258E-03 seconds
Weekend
This code ran successfully in 0.129999995231628 seconds
```

```
Sub RunFunction()

Dim StartTime, SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim FccstCCY As Variant
Dim DateLoop As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

FccstCCY = "ARS"
DateLoop = #12/31/2022#

StartTime = Timer
Debug.Print (FindValue(DateLoop, FccstCCY))
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print ("This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds")

StartTime = Timer
Debug.Print (FindValue2(DateLoop, FccstCCY))
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print ("This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds")

End Sub

Function FindValue(DateLoop As Variant, CCY As Variant) As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, LastColumn, R, C As Long
Dim StartCell As Range


Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws.Cells(StartCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Arr = ws.Range(StartCell, ws.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))


For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
        If Arr(R, 1) = DateLoop And Arr(R, 2) = CCY Then
            FindValue = Arr(R, 3)
        Exit Function
        End If
    Next C
Next R

End Function

Function FindValue2(rng1 As Variant, rng2 As Variant) As Variant
Dim varVal1 As Variant
Dim varVal2 As Variant
Dim rngTargetA As Range
Dim rngTargetB As Range
Dim lngRowCounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

varVal1 = rng1
varVal2 = rng2

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
lngRowCounter = 2
Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Do While Not IsEmpty(rngTargetA.Value)
    If rngTargetA.Value = varVal1 And rngTargetB.Value = varVal2 Then
        FindValue2 = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter).Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngRowCounter = lngRowCounter + 1
    Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
    Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Loop

' if we don't find anything, return an empty string '
FindValue2 = "Nothing"


End Function
```

Comment: Do not Loop ranges, that is slow.  Instead load the range into variant arrays and loop those instead.

Comment: For some suggestions on how to load the arrays mentioned by @ScottCraner, see the late Chip Pearson's article on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Do you really need code for this? You can do it with a LOOKUP formula.

Comment: You could write the concatenated values of columns `A` and `B` to the `keys`, and the associated values in column `C` to the `items` of a dictionary and easily access the relevant data. This function is useless (too slow) in the scenario you are describing since you have to loop through columns in a worksheet multiple times while by using the dictionary you would do this only once and you could use an array to loop through it instead of the columns and additionally increase efficiency. Why don't you share the code of the calling procedure so we can see what exactly can be done?

Comment: A quick win for speed increases is usually to turn off screen refreshes during execution. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the macro and include error control to ensure it gets reset to `TRUE` at the end of the macro.

Comment: Or just use a multi-variable match function such as `=INDEX(C$2:C$12, MATCH(D2&"#"&E2,A$2:A$12&"#"&B$2:B$12,0))`

Comment: If you want it to be faster than your latest version, then you'll have to show us the calling macro's code.

Comment: You posted a calling procedure that calls the function once. We need to see the real calling procedure to offer some improvements.

Comment: "a table with 10'000 rows" - is the data you're looking for on the last row?  That makes a big difference to the speed. Always best to test using a "worst case" scenario...   FYI some different approaches here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285   You'd be using a composite "key" value of the two search columns joined together with (eg) `Chr(0)`

Answer (score -1):

You can utilise worksheet functions within VBA so the following should work (although some playing around with date formats may be required because they never seem to play ball).

```
Sub FindVal()
    Debug.Print FindValue("12/31/2022", "ARS")
End Sub

Function FindValue(v1 As String, v2 As String) As String
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ColData As Range: Set ColData = wsSrc.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    Dim MatchFormula As String, IndexFormula As String
    
    MatchFormula = "Match(""" & v1 & "#" & v2 & """, " & ColData.Address & "&""#""&" & ColData.Offset(0, 1).Address & ", 0)"
    IndexFormula = "IfError(Index(" & ColData.Offset(0, 2).Address & ", " & MatchFormula & "), ""No Match"")"
    
    'Debug.Print IndexFormula
    FindValue = wsSrc.Evaluate(IndexFormula)
End Function
```